# Getting javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException when running a Quarkus microservice (Java based) having postgres DB integration

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am new to the Quarkus framework and I am stuck with the below error. Any suggestion would be very helpful on where is the issue.

**Error:**
`[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.abhishek.dao.PersonRepository and qualifiers [@Default] - java member: org.abhishek.resource.PersonResource#repository - declared on CLASS bean [types=[org.abhishek.resource.PersonResource, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=org.abhishek.resource.PersonResource]`

**Entity Class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

**Repository interfce:**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends PanacheRepository<PersonEntity> {
}
```

**Resource Class**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/persons")
public class PersonResource {

    @Inject
    PersonRepository repository;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<PersonEntity> list() {
        return repository.listAll();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void add(PersonEntity person) {
        repository.persist(person);
    }
}
```

I am trying to run my application and connect to the Postgres DB I am running locally on port 5432.

The application should be able to connect to the DB and create **persons** table and I would be able to hit the APIs configured. But getting the above error, which I am not able to resolve.

Comment: Where is an implementation of `PersonRepository`? You should provide at least one

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci, I am extending the PanacheRepository which took care the implementaions internally.

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#defining-your-repository: official doc example created a concrete @applicationscoped bean

Answer (score 0):

By adding the repository class which implements the PanacheRepository interface and then injecting this into the repository class solved my issue.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PersonRepository implements PanacheRepository<Person> {

   //can also add any custom logic methods based on the requirements

}
```

**Injecting it in the Resource/controller class:**

```
public class PersonResource {
    @Inject
    PersonRepository repository;
.........
.......

}
```